# How to check if image contains source?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

how can I check if image contains source ?

Before executing a piece of code, I would check whether the image has a source.

Comment: What is "source" in an "image"?

Comment: I mean Image control in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `Source` property is or is not equal to null.

```
if(img.Source != null)
{

}
else
{

}
```